# MySQL Basic about relationship

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

My doubt is about how to treat the follow thing:

I have a system where a user belong to a company, and this user have their clients.

How is the right way to get a list of all company clients and the follow user name??

In the client table where i have  a field with the one of this relations:

- A company_id and user_id field
- Just company_id field
- Just user_id field cause user table have the company_id???
- Something else...

Tkz
Roberto

Comment: We need more precise information. For example, can a client be a client of more than one user? Can a client be a client of more than one company? Can the same user work for more than one company? And if so, do they have two separate lists of clients, or the same list of clients at both companies?

Answer (score 1):

Tables relations:
Client (FK_companyId, FK_userId). "use FK_companyId only if you have multi-companies"
User (FK_companyId).
company (NO foreign keys for client or user).

if there is ONLY one company in the system then you don't need to include it in the relation:

`SELECT clientInfo FROM client where userId=userSessionId;`

if you have multi-companies then:
`SELECT client.clientInfo,client.companyId,company.companyInfo FROM client left join company on (client.companyId = company.Id) where userId=userSessionId;`

Note: the left join used to get the "company info" if its available but all user clients linked to that particular company will be retrieved.

Finally: If one client info can be managed by mutli users then you shall not link/couple the  the two entities together.

BTW: your English is horrible!

Comment: You should be more careful with your accusations, because your English isn't much better. "If there are only one company", "a user that belong", "if you multi-companies then", ...

Comment: dude, asking a question not like answering it!! while answering i care more about getting the question answered ASAP. but if the question poorly written then it will make a lot of people ignore it or hesitate to answer it. anyway thank for correcting my second language syntax :)

Comment: tkz for the info... my english is horrible but its better than nothing... you understood me... which is the objetive ;) tkz again and tkz Tom!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a select statement

```
SELECT company_id,user_id FROM client;
```

Comment: But what are the right way to construct the table ?? Which foreign index i put in the client table??